# Query to remove people from the list the moment they meet any 1 condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a suppression list using query. People who have made an order in 1 year or opened a email should not be excluded. Rest of the people should be in the list. For extracting this suppression list I have the below query

```
   /*no orders in 1Y */
    select CUSTOMER_UUID 
    from Customers
    where last_transaction_date <= DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())
    UNION
    /*No opens */
    Select distinct CUSTOMER_UUID 
    from [email_no_opens]
```

But the issue is if customer has opened email and not made an order, the customer is still in the suppression list. I want them not to be there the moment they take have opened email  or made an order.

I am confused on how to modify this query.

Comment: What does your list represent? People that should be excluded? Your title says to "remove ... from list" which implies you want a list of people to be INCLUDED.

Answer (score -2):

You have 2 sub queries and want to select entries which are results of both - first and second sub query. In this case you should use `INTERSECT` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an actual answer